# jQuery Animate backgroundPosition not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-position

I'm attempting to animate background position of some divs followed by a callback animation that does the same.

What am I missing here? 
HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class='divimg'></div>
    <div class='divimg'></div>
    <div class='divimg'></div>
</div>
​
```

CSS:

```
.divimg {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    margin:20px;
    float:left;
    background-size: 500px 500px;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no repeat;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/186/116/nature/1);
}​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() { 
    function animateGrid() {  
        $('.divimg').animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"bottom center"}, 
            500, function() { 
                $('.divimg').animate(
                    {backgroundPosition:"top center"}, 
                500)
            }
        );   
    }
    animateGrid(); 
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jc6212/WPF6H/2/

Comment: jQuery is known to not animate composite/text value properties properly, but it is possible to workaround.

Comment: In Chrome, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WPF6H/3/) can be used, for Firefox you'd have to create a CSS Hook.

Comment: I see, so with jQuery animations it's a better practice to stick with integers instead of text value properties. This will be easier when changing the value anyway - Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From [`.animate()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; [...]
>   Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. font, background, border) are not fully supported.

To animate just the `backgroundPositionY` as you're doing, in Chrome you can simply animate said property. As Firefox does not support `backgroundPositionY`, you can apply a [CSS Hook](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/) for browsers that do not support it:

```
if (!('backgroundPositionY' in document.createElement('div').style)) {
    $.cssHooks.backgroundPositionY = {
        get: function(elem, computed, extra) {
            return $.css(elem, 'backgroundPosition').split(' ')[1];
        },
        set: function(elem, value) {
            elem.style.backgroundPosition = $.css(elem, 'backgroundPosition').split(' ')[0] + ' ' + value;
        }
    };
}


$(function() {

    function animateGrid() {
        $('.divimg').animate({
            backgroundPositionY: 250
        }, 500, function() {
            $('.divimg').animate({
                backgroundPositionY: 0
            }, 500);
        });
    }

    animateGrid();
});
```

Tested in Chrome, FF, IE9. Should work in all browsers.

### [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/WPF6H/30/)