# jQuery .animate issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-position

I have the following piece of code.

```
           if ($(checkboxID)[0].checked == false) {
                $(this).animate({
                    'background-position-x': '0%',
                    'background-position-y': '0%'
                }, 200, 'linear');

                $(checkboxID)[0].checked = true;
                $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');

            } else {
                $(this).animate({
                    'background-position-x': '100%',
                    'background-position-y': '0%'
                }, 200, 'linear');

                $(checkboxID)[0].checked = false;
                $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');

            }
```

As you can see the code is identical in both sides of the if, but if it's true the jquery doesn't animate the transition, no matter how much I increase the duration.
Can any of you see an error here I missed?

EDIT: Here is the css too:

```
    .checkbox-style  {
    display: block;
    width: 87px;
    height: 28px;
    background: url('images/check-square.png') no-repeat;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
   .on {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
   }
   .off {
    background-position: 100% 0%;
   }
```

Comment: May be provide a JSFiddle.

Comment: You need to use backgroundPositionX ... but it only works in chrome, here is a cross-browser solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442897/jquery-animate-backgroundposition-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess a little, but I suppose elements with the `off` class aren't visible. As the class change is executed immediately, you don't have the time to see the animation.

You probably wanted the class to be changed at the end of the animation. To do it, pass a callback to `animate`, it will be called when the animation is complete :

```
           $(this).animate({
                'background-position-x': '100%',
                'background-position-y': '0%'
            }, 200, 'linear', function(){
               $(checkboxID)[0].checked = false;
               $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
            });
```

Comment: This is a div replacement of a checkbox. here is the css for those .checkbox-style  {
 display: block;
 width: 87px;
 height: 28px;
 background: url('images/check-square.png') no-repeat;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 overflow: hidden;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.on {
 background-position: 0% 0%;
}
.off {
 background-position: 100% 0%;
}